Next.js 502 Bad Gateway Error with Image Optimization on Vercel
I'm experiencing an issue with my Next.js application that is deployed on Vercel. The problem is related to image optimization. The images are being loaded from an external WordPress site, and I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error in the browser console. This issue only occurs with external images and the specific error in the console is:
GET https://assetcleaning.co.nz/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgurpreetd12.sg-host.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2023%2F11%2Fgenerativ-ai.jpg&w=2048&q=75 502 (Bad Gateway)
npm warn ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm warn While resolving: @typescript-eslint/parser@7.2.0
npm warn Found: eslint@8.48.0
npm warn node_modules/eslint
npm warn Could not resolve dependency:
npm warn peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@7.2.0
npm warn Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
Ensured that the external image domains are listed in the next.config.js under images.domains.
Checked that the image URLs are correct and accessible directly via a browser.
Images are loading in DEV environment. No issues there.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
